# Fix button alignment when content pushes it down

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a few products using HTML & CSS only.

An issue I'm facing is that when the content in the  exceeds a certain amount, it pushes everything down, making the alignment uneven (see 3rd product in image). How can I go about making so everything is in alignment?

My thoughts are to have the h2 tag have enough space to cover 2 or 3 lines worth (I don't have products longer than 2 lines). So the read more, grams and button will remain fixed and inline.

Any ideas how I can achieve that or any recommendations? I've pasted the codepen, code & image for reference

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/QasimArif/pen/MWKVBRr)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:200,300,400,500);
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

h2 {
  color: #303457;
  margin: 2rem 0 .5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

img {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/*** Cards ***/

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.card {
  /*height: 200px;*/
  /*background: red;*/
  padding: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  /* -webkit-box-orient: vertical; */
  /* -webkit-box-direction: normal; */
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  color: #5d5e5e;
}

.thumbnail img {
  fill: #c7c4c4;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card-content {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-content p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

a.read_more {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p.product_grams {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #303457;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #3F457E;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.btn:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="cards">

      <!--   card 1 -->
      <article class="card">
        <picture class="thumbnail">
          <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_8847d478-f0c4-431f-b660-8eb422b8960b.jpg?v=1594121528" alt="" />
        </picture>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2>American Hard Gums</h2>
          <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
          <p class="product_grams">80g</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </article>

      <!--   card 2 -->
      <article class="card">
        <picture class="thumbnail">
          <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_21a4c85d-0672-453e-a7c1-b3e91f124dd4.jpg?v=1594121533" alt="" />
        </picture>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2>Dracula Teeth</h2>
          <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
          <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </article>

      <!--   card 3 -->
      <article class="card">
        <picture class="thumbnail">
          <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_2cd47a09-ab57-4e6c-bfc6-f9db38d0158c.jpg?v=1594121547" alt="" />
        </picture>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2>Fizzy Blue Jelly Babies</h2>
          <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
          <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </article>

      <!--   card 4 -->
      <article class="card">
        <picture class="thumbnail">
          <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_35abd0b2-5a5e-489f-b4d1-370fc7ae3bd0.jpg?v=1594121518" alt="" />
        </picture>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2>Fizzy Cola Bottles</h2>
          <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
          <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </article>

      <!--   card 5 -->
      <article class="card">
        <picture class="thumbnail">
          <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_35008077-9942-4509-8b73-cfcf0ac91966.jpg?v=1594121521" alt="" />
        </picture>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2>Fizzy Strawberries</h2>
          <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
          <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </article>

      <!--   card 6 -->
      <article class="card">
        <picture class="thumbnail">
          <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_312016b2-59ce-4710-8f92-ba8d52914366.jpg?v=1594121525" alt="" />
        </picture>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h2>Peach Rings</h2>
          <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
          <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </article>

    </section>

  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: which way could you prefer to solve your issues? when text in `head` trying to overflow either reduce the font size of head or reduce the margin between them (`head` `paragraph` `button`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Hope it solved your problem.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:200,300,400,500);

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}

body {
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

h2 {
    color: #303457;
    margin: 2rem 0 .5rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
}

img {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cards {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr)); 
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.card {
    padding: .5rem;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    color: #5d5e5e;
}

.thumbnail img {
    fill: #c7c4c4;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.card-content {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-content p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.card-content h2{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

a.read_more {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}

p.product_grams {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #303457;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #3F457E;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.btn:active {
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <section class="cards">
                
                <!--   card 1 -->
                <article class="card">
                    <picture class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_8847d478-f0c4-431f-b660-8eb422b8960b.jpg?v=1594121528" alt="" />
                    </picture>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h2>American Hard Gums</h2>
                        <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
                        <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <!--   card 2 -->
                <article class="card">
                    <picture class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_21a4c85d-0672-453e-a7c1-b3e91f124dd4.jpg?v=1594121533" alt="" />
                    </picture>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h2>Dracula Teeth</h2>
                        <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
                        <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </article>

            <!--   card 3 -->
                <article class="card">
                    <picture class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_2cd47a09-ab57-4e6c-bfc6-f9db38d0158c.jpg?v=1594121547" alt="" />
                    </picture>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h2>Fizzy Blue Jelly Babies</h2>
                        <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
                        <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </article>

            <!--   card 4 -->
            <article class="card">
                <picture class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/7008/8604/products/image_35abd0b2-5a5e-489f-b4d1-370fc7ae3bd0.jpg?v=1594121518" alt="" />
                </picture>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2>Fizzy Cola Bottles</h2>
                    <a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
                    <p class="product_grams">80 grams</p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
                </div>
            </article>
        
            </section>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the height of the H2 a half of the line height (if you say there will not be more than 2 lines).

In your case these values should work:

```
h2 {
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 70px;
}
```